Order of qualifiers 'wailing' / 'dismal'
Is this the correct order of adjectives?:
"the wailing dismal zephyr tide"
Not using commas.
This is the whole sentence:

She stood against the wailing dismal zephyr tide of bodies, whose stench was an affront to the heavens, one even more ravenous than her madness.


Are you familiar with the rule for adjective order or what to do when there's a tie? (Although zephyr seems to be an attributive noun, not an adjective.)

I might expect dismal first, but zephyr sounds pleasant while dismal and stench are not.

'Zephyr' must, as an attributive noun, immediately precede the head noun. I'd say that with the other two, it's author's preference. '... dismal wailing ...' sounds more smooth-running (as I suspect Yosef has in mind), but ' ... the wailing ~ dismal ~ zephyr tide of bodies', where italics show stress and tildes each indicate where I'd leave a slight pause (slighter even than that of a comma) also works imo.

Trying to categorise 'dismal' and 'wailing' (1) will be dependent on the rule one chooses, (2) might lead to disagreement on which class 'wailing' falls in, and (3) even if (1) and (2) are negotiated, should be done bearing in mind that each categorisation scheme (so far, and afaIk) has been shown to have exceptions.

a zephyr is a soft breeze, so wailing and dismal do not collocate too well with it.

Lambie is quite right. In fact, the connection with 'Zephyrus [who] is the most gentle and favourable of the winds, ... also associated with flowers, springtime and even procreation' [Wikipedia] makes the collocation worse than 'not too [good]'. 'Boreal' would work better unless there are other reasons not to use it. // Then again, does the tide wail?
